# Passing two datetime parameters to SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql

I've struggling to find the solution for this error while constantly getting MySQL 1064.

My code:

```
query = "SELECT iv_alert.sensorId, iv_alert.sensorAlertUUID, 
iv_packetlog.packetData FROM iv_alert LEFT JOIN iv_packetlog ON 
iv_alert.packetLogId = iv_packetlog.packetLogId WHERE 
iv_packetlog.creationTime > %s AND iv_packetlog.creationTime <= %s"

args=lastquerytime, lasttime
cursor.execute(query,args)
```

Produces the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your 
SQL syntax ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near \') AND iv_packetlog.creationTime <= 
("\'2017-08-09 14:53:21\'",)\' at line 1')
```

At the same time, passing just one parameter works well:

```
query = "SELECT iv_alert.sensorId, iv_alert.sensorAlertUUID, 
iv_packetlog.packetData FROM iv_alert LEFT JOIN iv_packetlog ON 
iv_alert.packetLogId = iv_packetlog.packetLogId WHERE 
iv_packetlog.creationTime > %s"

args=lasttime
cursor.execute(query,args)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

Comment: Not sure if it works after replacing __%s__ with __?__ question mark

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, now I am getting this:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "grabPCAPs.py", line 76, in <module>
    getPCAP()
    File "grabPCAPs.py", line 41, in getPCAP
    cursor.execute(query,args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 159, in 
    execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Forget my comment. It was just a guess :p

Comment: You need quotes around your parameters

Comment: By the way, did you verify your sql query is correct?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Exactly I was trying to say that. Please answer that

Comment: If quotes are needed, why do I not receive any error using one parameter instead of two?
UPD: Just checked - quotes around parameters don't help, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding brackets around the query and make the args a tuple:

```
query = ("SELECT iv_alert.sensorId, iv_alert.sensorAlertUUID,"
         "iv_packetlog.packetData FROM iv_alert LEFT JOIN iv_packetlog ON"
         "iv_alert.packetLogId = iv_packetlog.packetLogId WHERE"
         "iv_packetlog.creationTime > %s AND iv_packetlog.creationTime <= %s")

args = (lastquerytime, lasttime)
cursor.execute(query, args)
```

You can see the same [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Getting same error still (1064).

Comment: @NickBabkin did you try using `BETWEEN %s AND %s` instead of `iv_packetlog.creationTime > %s AND iv_packetlog.creationTime <= %s`? maybe that will do the trick?

Comment: No I did not, because I previously ran this query in GUI MySQL client and it worked well, meaning that syntax is correct.

Comment: @NickBabkin, Sorry, then I'm out of ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's the solution:

Instead of:

```
args=lastquerytime, lasttime
```

Pass this:

```
args=(lastquerytime + lasttime)
```

To make it one unified tuple.